# Excel : sum of values depending of other values

Tags: sql, excel, sum, equivalent

What would be the equivalent Excel formula of this SQL query

```
SELECT SUM(a) FROM table WHERE b < 0;

A     B
----  ----
   1     0
   2    -1 
   3     4
   5    -3

>> 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"<0",A:A)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SUMIF` function.

Comment: That's what I tried, but if I'm not mistaken, the condition is only on one cell or an equality. `SUMIF(B1:B4;<0;A1:A4)` obviously doesn't work, but what to write before the `<`?

Answer (score 0):

use SUMIFS(a1:a4,b1:b4,"<0") if values in A1:B4 range

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
Row#    A    B

3       1    0
4       2   -1
5       3    4
6       5   -3

=SUMIF(B3:B6; "<0"; A3:A6)
```